# ASP.net checkbox state is not being read correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview displaying some data, with an added checkbox column so I can remove select items.  My gridview is laid out like so:

```
<div class = "my_gv">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID = "update_panel" UpdateMode = "Conditional" runat = "server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="my_gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" 
                    GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" 
                    CssClass="table table-bordered x-condensed cameraDetails" OnRowDataBound = "my_gv_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectAll_ChckBx" runat="server" onclick="selectAllCheckBoxes(this);" meta:resourceKey="SelectAll_ChckBxResource1" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="row_select_checkbox" runat="server" meta:resourceKey="row_select_checkbox_resource" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="CAMheader" />
                            <ItemStyle CssClass="itemEntry chkBx" Width="25px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        // snip
```

My logic to handle the delete does the following:

```
            foreach (GridViewRow row in my_gv.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var chkBox = row.FindControl("row_select_checkbox");

                if (chkBox.Checked)
                { 
                    // snip
                }
```

This seems to make sense to me, but the .Checked method is always returning false, regardless of the actual state of the checkbox.  I'm able to access other (textual) columns from the gridview just fine.

So, what am I doing wrong?  How can I accurately get the checkbox state?  Thanks for any help

Comment: I must ask, where is this code snippet located exactly. What page method.

Comment: @MikeC. The gridview is defined in the .aspx body.  The delete logic is in a function that is called when a "Delete" button is pressed.  The function gets called at the correct time

Comment: Are you sure about the ID being the same as execution. Meaning do u think it's unable to locate the id("row_select_checkbox"), because may be id has changed ?

Comment: Can you put a break point on this line: var chkBox = row.FindControl("row_select_checkbox"); and check if you get any value for chkBox ?

Comment: Without seeing your code, my money is on you are rebinding the GridView on postback and it is wiping out any checkboxes that were checked, thus the Checked property is false.

Comment: @Karl This seems like the most likely reasoning...but shouldn't the code-click functionality run before posting back?

Comment: @zebra - nope, `page_load` gets run before any click handlers. So wrap your binding in an `if (!IsPostBack)` - this will prevent it binding on the postback - rebind it after the click if you need to.

Comment: No, page_load happens first. Here is the MSDN ASP.NET page lifecycle documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making a BindGrid method that does the work of getting the list of data to bind to the grid and then actually calling DataBind, the method could optionally accept a List that way all the method does is just bind to a GridView.  Then you could do the following in your page_load:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    BindGrid();
}
```

This gives you the flexibility of calling the binding logic again if you need to grid to be updated (i.e. paging or sorting of the grid).